# How to get the particular word from response in jmeter Regular Expression extractor

Tags: java, regex, jmeter

I am trying to extract the last value from the string in Jmeter Regular Expression extractor.

My string

```
Server.init("asdfasd4ffffasdf", "http://x.x.x.x:8888/", "asdf-U-Yasdf77asdf99");
```

I want to get only `asdf-U-Yasdf77asdf99`.

I tried something like the below, but not correct:

```
Server.init\(".+", ".+", "([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)"\);
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that your regex is "not correct"? How are you using it and what results you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JMeter` you need to reference your match group.

```
Reference Name: MYWORD
Regular Expression: Server\.init\("[^"]+", "[^"]+", "([^"]+)"\);
Template: $1$
```

Your captured match can be accessed by using `${MYWORD}`

If you specify using a `Match No:` above, use the corresponding value to access the match.

Comment: Awesome. It would work, but I changed little bit from your solution. Server.init\(".+?", ".+?", "(.+?)"\);

Answer (score 1):

That regex, while not very beautiful, should work when used correctly. But you need to look at the result of group 1, not the entire match.

So you need to do something like

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Server\\.init\\(\"[^\"]+\", \"[^\"]+\", \"([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)\"\\);");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression:

```
Server.init\("(.+?)",\s"(.+?)",\s"(.+?)"
```

Matches the following string

```
Server.init("asdfasd4ffffasdf", "http://x.x.x.x:8888/", "asdf-U-Yasdf77asdf99"
```

we can extract the following values in `jmeter`:

- `$1` values = `asdfasd4ffffasdf`
- `$2` values = `http://x.x.x.x:8888/`
- `$3` values = `asdf-U-Yasdf77asdf99`